# How do I remove the Author name and image from the Breeze template for Blogger

Tags: html, css, templates, blogs, blogger

I am using the following theme on a new blog:
http://www.themexpose.com/2014/07/breeze-responsive-personal-blogger.html

but I would like to remove the author image and name that it places on the posts on the home page. I have already unticked it under the post setting under layout.

I have managed to get it to display as I want by setting {display: none} to the css at the appropriate point, but the author name is still passed to the client if not displayed. I would like to stop it from appearing in the source of the page as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the theme and remove the XML that is expressing the authorname. It looks like this:

```
  <data:post.author/>
```

It's present in a few places throughout the theme (it looks like there's a separate mobile layout, for example, which uses this). Find it & take it out, that should remove it from the mark-up delivered to the browser.

Comment: This removes the name, but the Image still remains